# Integrating hadoop yarn with mesos infra

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I have created a hdfs cluster .  I have to configure yarn so as to allow yarn application master to be able to create containers for job processing on the mesos cluster on demand .

how can i integrate the hdfs cluster with the mesos infra so that it can create containers on mesos ?

i need to figure out a way to run the containers created by the application master on another resources apart from the YARN cluster ( a client node, or edge node, or the resources spun through mesos infra ) . basically , i have to create an on-demand ,compute only cluster which can run the yarn apps once yarn is used up

Answer (score 0):

Mesos was created as a more generic version of YARN, they're not really intended to be used together (YARN apps cannot be deployed to Mesos). Spark apps are about the only process in the whole Hadoop ecosystem that can be deployed (independently) to both.

Worth pointing out that Mesos was moved to Apache Attic (edit: and quickly moved out, it seems, but there's been no releases since then). In other words, it's seen as deprecated. With a bit of configuration, YARN can run plain Docker containers, if that's what you're using Mesos for. Apache Twill was a library for creating distributed applications on top of YARN, but that's also in the Apache Attic (and stayed).

You also don't need special configurations to communicate with HDFS from Mesos applications, only the `hadoop-client` dependency and a configured `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` file

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but i need to figure out a way to run the containers created by the application master on another resources apart from the hdfs cluster ( a client node ore edge node or the resources spun through mesos infra ) . basically , i have to create an on-demand ,compute only cluster which can run the yarn apps once the hdfs cluster is used up

Comment: Like I said, there's no way (builtin to either Mesos or YARN) to "offload" applications between each other. You'd therefore have to build your own scheduler abstraction over them. Also, HDFS is irrelevant to the question - it's YARN that's running the apps in Hadoop, not the "hdfs cluster"

Comment: There's also no way for `hadoop jar` or similar processes (Hive, Oozie, etc) to be deployed directly to Mesos, as they explicitly rely on `yarn-site.xml` to point at the YARN resource manager server. Only Spark has options for using a Mesos master, but it wouldn't use both that and YARN for the same application